# exception-handling is all about exceptions

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Is there any reason we have both [exceptions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exceptions) and [exception-handling](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exception-handling)?

Imho, the latter should be merged into the former, or at least synonymized, as there's no relevant difference between their topics.

Comment: I suppose you could argue exception throwing and exception handling are two separate activities...but I can't imagine how you'd ask a question about one and not the other. Agree with merging.

Comment: A quick look at the Exceptions tag makes me think there might be some valid questions about Exceptions themselves that wouldn't really make sense being tagged with exception-handling. For example, if/when to create your own exceptions, or to inherit from them, or using them as event arguments etc

Comment: @Rachel: That would be tagged [tag:exceptions], and maybe [tag:class-design] or [tag:inheritance] - depending on the specifics.

Comment: @Deduplicator Oops, I read this as merging exceptions into exception-handling. Yes it would probably make sense to merge exception-handling into exceptions :)

Comment: @Rachel: Yes, *this time* I didn't swap them... (though I had to look at it once more to be sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synonym suggestion has been placed in the system. It now needs a couple of (up) votes at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/exceptions/synonyms to take effect.

Comment: It took me forever to remember where you go to vote on this, so to save everyone else some time: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/exceptions/synonyms